# How do I install globus toolkit?

Tags: software-installation

I'm doing a project on "grid Computing" and more specifically on "GRAM: job execution/resource management". I'm trying to install "Globus Toolkit".

Answer (score 1):

For installing Globus Toolkit nothing more easy than download the latest package:

```
wget http://toolkit.globus.org/ftppub/gt6/installers/repo/globus-toolkit-repo_latest_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i globus-toolkit-repo_latest_all.deb
```

Update the repositories: `sudo apt-get update`

Then install your desired package, using `sudo apt-get install package` being package any of these:

`globus-gridftp`
    GridFTP client and server tools

`globus-gram5`
    GRAM5 client and server tools

`globus-gsi`
    Globus Security Infrastructure tools for managing certificates and proxies

`globus-data-management-server`
    Server tools for deploying a GridFTP server.

`globus-data-management-client`
    Client Tools for data management, including the GridFTP client programs and globus-url-copy

`globus-data-management-sdk`
    Development headers and documentation for writing applications using the GridFTP APIs.

`globus-resource-management-server`
    Server tools for deploying a GRAM5 resource manager

`globus-resource-management-client`
    Client tools for resource management, including the globusrun tool, and the globus-job-* tools.

`globus-resource-management-sdk`
    Development headers and documentation for writing applications using the GRAM5 APIs.

Source:

http://toolkit.globus.org/toolkit/docs/6.0/admin/install/#gtadmin-install